# External API Calls - Data Access Layer or Service Layer?

Tags: service-layer, n-tier-architecture, picasa

I have an N-tiered application:

1. Database
2. Domain Layer
3. Data Access Layer
4. Service Layer
5. Presentation Layers (iOS, Android, MVC 3)

I am trying to employ the Google Api for Picasa for users to upload photos. Where is a good place to put the logic for uploading functionality, picasa authentication in the Data Access Layer or in IImageService within my Service Layer?

I *think* it should be within the Service Layer but I am not totally sure.

I also have a Domain Class for Images

```
 public class Image
 {
    public int ImageId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Src {get; set;}
    public string AltText {get; set;}
 }
```

Comment: Though posted later, this was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444690/where-does-web-api-fit-in-a-typical-n-tier-architecture