# Web API as decoupled service layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a REST API to provide services for **Mobile** and my **SPA** project. I want to decoupled the `Web API` from my `ASP.NET MVC`.

How do I suppose to consume my `Web API` from my front-end `ASP.NET MVC`?

I saw this post, but had no examples [Where does Web API fit in a typical n-tier architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444690/where-does-web-api-fit-in-a-typical-n-tier-architecture).

Answer (score 1):

You can consume your Web API Methods from your MVC Application via http using the HttpClient class. Like so:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/");

            string actionString = string.Format("api/GetSomething/{0}?count={1}", "someId", 5);
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(actionString).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // do something
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that you have your front end MVC and your Web API in the same project, possibly sharing the same model objects, is this correct?

If this is correct and you want to decouple them, here's how I've approached it.

First, create 3 separate projects. One would contain your front-end, the second, your Web API and perhaps data access logic (if you want, this could even be another data access layer project only called by the Web API) and, lastly, a common object definition library.

The common objects library would not contain any code beyond definitions of inheritable objects and interfaces. This project would be added as a reference to both the Web API and front end MVC projects and should be easy enough to replicate in your mobile development languages. This puts all of your apps on the same page object-wise and this makes your development tasks much easier.

Second, I created a ApiGateway class the MVC front end uses to call the Web API. This class uses reflection to load the results from the API call into objects from my definitions library. You can also introduce some common server side caching and error handling at this point as well.

Let me know if you need further clarification of this technique.